# Make monitor pitch black outside of opened window?

Tags: windows-10

I play a game in windowed mode, it takes up about 1/2 of my monitor area. I want this game window to be positioned in the exact middle of my larger monitor, and I want everything on the screen outside of that window to be pitch black, so it's just that window that's showing. Basically, I want to pretend/simulate a fullscreen application and not see other stuff on my screen. How can I do this?

Comment: 'Dumb/simple' solution might be to hide the taskbar, and set a monochrome/black background?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That solves the black background, still need to precisely center the window (I want it exact so it's not in a slightly different spot each session)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - 2 steps to this

You want a blank background, hidden taskbar and such. I feel like a tool that's nothing more than one or more windows that's just a block of colour would work well with the rest of it, but I'm not aware of one.

Then you can use a set of tools from the [powertoys family](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) of tools from microsoft

There's alternatives from other companies that do the very same thing, and naturally feel free to use what works for you.

Use [Fancyzones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/fancyzones) to set up a grid that'll fit your needs  I'd go with 3 columns, and splitting the middle column into 3. This would allow you to precisely and *replicably* have a window always on the same place. You might also consider hiding your desktop icons under the game window location :D

You might find (and I haven't tested these together) being able to pin the game window on top, and to set a border on it with the [Always in top utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/always-on-top)